# How to solve "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery" in safari browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

If my web opened in chrome and firefox browser, it's no error

But, if it opened in safari browser, there exist error like this :

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Object.assign')
>
> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Object.assign')

`Object.assign` is an EcmaScript 2015 (ES2015) addition that, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), is only available starting in Safari 9. If you're using a library that requires ES2015 and have a requirement to support Safari 8, then you'll need to use a transpiler to convert the ES2015 code into ES5.

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery

This error could be due to:

- not including jQuery in your code.
- including code that depends on jQuery before including jQuery itself.
- the previous error preventing further execution of JavaScript.

Comment: I use windows 10. Where can I download safari 9 for windows 10? I just found safari 5.1.7. In chrome and firefox browser, it's no error